# Beat frequency and phase difference

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

Equation for mechanical wave:

$$ y = A \sin \left( k x \pm \omega t \right) \tag{1} \label{1} $$

Here, $k = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength and $\omega = 2 \pi f$, the angular frequency with $f$ the temporal frequency.

But when deriving the equation for beat frequency we count the equation for wave as

$$ y = A \sin \left( \omega t \right) \tag{2} \label{2} $$

Why is the phase difference ignored in deriving an equation for beat frequency?Is it make any issue if we count the equation as $$ y = A \sin \left( k x \pm \omega t \right)$$

Comment: what is the phase between two waves of *different* frequencies?

Comment: The second equation is not the equation for a wave. Maybe you mean beat frequency between two oscillators.

Comment: I don't know what is the phase between two waves of different frequencies. But in physics books the phase difference is ignored without showing any reason or describing the reason.So I asked this question.

Comment: Have you tried to derive the beating equation using the solution of equation 1 instead of equation 2? I believe this will provide some insight in your question.

Comment: hint: just take two oscillations of equal amplitude: $y_1=A\sin(\omega_1 t +\phi_1)$ and $y_1=A\sin(\omega_2 t +\phi_2)$, now calculate the beat and try to interpret its "phase".

Comment: Probably to make the derivation simpler a position $x=0$ was chosen and the superposition of $y_1 = A \sin \left( \omega_1 t \right)$ and $y_2= A \sin \left( \omega_2 t \right)$ was used?

Answer (score 0):

Please go ahead and use the travelling waves to derive the beat frequency. You will see that it yields the correct result. However, my recommendation is to use a small program to visualise the effect. E.g.

```
wave = function(t, x, T=1, lambda=1, phi=0){
    return( sin(2*pi/T*t + 2*pi/lambda*x + phi) )
}

x = linspace(0, 50, 507)
y = wave(t=0, x, lambda=1) + wave(t=0, x, lambda=1.05, phi=0) 

df = data.frame(x,y)
library(ggplot2)
gg = ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
print(gg)
```

generates the following plot:

[image]

By playing with the numbers, you can easily confirm that the result is as expected.